# One page checkout login fail (integrity constraint violation 1452)

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, login

I have a problem on my Magento website, as the login on the one page checkout doesn't work (the classic one does). When I try to login from the checkout page, it just refresh the page and do nothing (no error message and no logs).

I investigated on that problem and I discoverd that in the file `app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php` inside the method `loginPostAction()` there is a commented line:

```
// Mage::logException($e); // PA DSS violation: this exception log can disclose customer password
```

If you uncomment this line, an exception appears in the log files:

```
Next exception 'Zend_Db_Statement_Exception' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`bbmarketplace`.`magentosales_flat_quote_shipping_rate`, CONSTRAINT `FK_8A798F8F0479792A74EFD849B1C80E74` FOREIGN KEY (`address_id`) REFERENCES `magentosales_flat_quote_address` (`address_id`)), query was: INSERT INTO `magentosales_flat_quote_shipping_rate` (`address_id`, `created_at`, `updated_at`, `carrier`, `carrier_title`, `code`, `method`, `method_description`, `price`, `method_title`, `udropship_vendor`) VALUES (?, '2015-05-13 12:20:58', '2015-05-13 12:20:58', ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)'
```

After some more investigation, I discovered this problem comes from the method `setQuoteGuest()` inside the file `app/code/Mage/Persistent/Model/Observer.php`:

```
 public function setQuoteGuest($checkQuote = false)
    {
        /** @var $quote Mage_Sales_Model_Quote */
        $quote = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
        if ($quote && $quote->getId()) {
            if ($checkQuote && !Mage::helper('persistent')->isShoppingCartPersist() && !$quote->getIsPersistent()) {
                Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->unsetAll();
                return;
            }

            $quote->getPaymentsCollection()->walk('delete');
            $quote->getAddressesCollection()->walk('delete');
            $this->_setQuotePersistent = false;
            $quote
                ->setIsActive(true)
                ->setCustomerId(null)
                ->setCustomerEmail(null)
                ->setCustomerFirstname(null)
                ->setCustomerLastname(null)
                ->setCustomerGroupId(Mage_Customer_Model_Group::NOT_LOGGED_IN_ID)
                ->setIsPersistent(false)
                ->removeAllAddresses();
            //Create guest addresses
            $quote->getShippingAddress();
            $quote->getBillingAddress();
            $quote->collectTotals()->save();
        }

        $this->_getPersistentHelper()->getSession()->removePersistentCookie();
    }
```

To solve my problem, I've overwritten the file and commented the line `$quote->getAddressesCollection()->walk('delete');`.

Now it works fine, but I really would like to know why I have to comment that line in order to be able to log in on the checkout page.

I don't really understand what this method does and why I have to comment this line, and it bother me. I get that it solve the constraint violation, but I would like to know why I've got this violation in the first place.

thank you